# android google map finding distance

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, distance, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find distance between two locations. I have longitudes and latitudes and I can calculate Euclidean distance. But I want to find road distance. I mean, , I want to calculate the distance of the road that I am going on while going to destination from source. In this case how to calculate this?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way would be to use the Google Directions API to get the directions, this gives you a list of all the points along the route (and the total distance).

Check out : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

If your not sure how to do this let me know and i'll post some code for you which will get the directions from google and extract the data you need.

UPDATE - CODE AS REQUESTED

```
private void GetDistance(GeoPoint src, GeoPoint dest) {

    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
    urlString.append("origin=");//from
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append("&destination=");//to
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append("&mode=walking&sensor=true");
    Log.d("xxx","URL="+urlString.toString());

    // get the JSON And parse it to get the directions data.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
    URL url = null;

    url = new URL(urlString.toString());
    urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    InputStream inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

    String temp, response = "";
    while((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null){
        //Parse data
        response += temp;
    }
    //Close the reader, stream & connection
    bReader.close();
    inStream.close();
    urlConnection.disconnect();

    //Sortout JSONresponse 
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("routes");
        //Log.d("JSON","array: "+array.toString());

    //Routes is a combination of objects and arrays
    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
        //Log.d("JSON","routes: "+routes.toString());

    String summary = routes.getString("summary");
        //Log.d("JSON","summary: "+summary);

    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
        //Log.d("JSON","legs: "+legs.toString());

    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
            //Log.d("JSON","steps: "+steps.toString());

    JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        //Log.d("JSON","distance: "+distance.toString());

            String sDistance = distance.getString("text");
            int iDistance = distance.getInt("value");

}
```

This will return the distance between the two points, you can change the function to return it as a string or as an integer, just return either sDistance or iDistance.

Hope this helps you, let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Zhehao Mao's answer is probably better if you just want the distance, it depends what you want to do once you have the distance, if you want to plot a route on your map then use the Directions API.

Comment: I examined the page that you send and i think if you can send some code part it wpuld be better for me. SO could you post some code?

Comment: I've added the code to my original answer.
BTW you cant do it the way @Khepri said on android - it would be alot easier though!

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps. It really helped me. As ı know direction api gives and order via waypoints as response of travelling salesman problem. Now one more question is that, how to parse this json file. How is the order? i mean if i set parameter optimization as true, how is the result? Only the optimized result? And the main question is that how to parse? What does it mean if there is two route in routers array? I think legs is one direction from a place to place. But if yes , what is route? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I tried the code you posted above but when compiling in Eclipse Android the following error is received: "*JSONTokener cannot be resolved to a type*" for the line of code: `JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new **JSONTokener**(response).nextValue();` One of the 'fixes' is to Import JSONTokener(org.json), but if I do this then it throws up a whole bunch of other errors, such as: "*Unhandled exception type IOException*" for the code: `inStream.close();` Unfortunately I am fairly new to Android and Java, so if you are able to offer any suggestions it would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Kevin - you would need to import JSONTokener, the reason you are getting errors is because you have to surround the tokener with a try, catch statement that will catch the JSON exceptions if they occur

Answer (score 5):

Use the google maps distance matrix API http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already working with google-maps, take a look at [the driving directions api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/).

(BTW, Google Maps API v3? I'm going to assume yes)

For a pair of lat/lng points, you can make a request for driving directions

In API3 it would look something like so:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var start = from; // A Google LatLng point or an address, 
                  // see their API for further details
var end = to;     // A Google LatLng point or an address, 
                  //see their API for further details

var request = {
origin: start,
destination: end,
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
   //Check if status Ok
   //Distance will be in response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text

});
```

Verify that a response status was ok, and then make sure there is a routes collection. if so, there's a result and you can access the "distance" text element via:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I saw couple of people have answered it correctly but have a look to this answer. Very useful api for using Google Map direction api. [Google Maps Direction Api usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053901/351708)

Answer (score 0):

Kenny's improved answer that is working for me, I have modified few things according to me. As LatLng is introduced instead of geopoint. I am posting working code which is modified version of Kenny's answer. All credits goes to kenny not me!

**Important point :**

**Pass the address in string format. for eg : toronto**

copy this function :

```
private void GetDistance(String src, String dest) {

        String s = src.replaceAll("\\s","+");
        String d = dest.replaceAll("\\s","+");

        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
        urlString.append("origin=");
        urlString.append((s));
        urlString.append("&destination=");
        urlString.append((d));
        urlString.append("&mode=driving&sensor=true");
        Log.d("xxx", "URL=" + urlString.toString());

        // get the JSON And parse it to get the directions data.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

            String temp, response = "";
            while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Parse data
                response += temp;
            }
            //Close the reader, stream & connection
            bReader.close();
            inStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();

            //Sortout JSONresponse
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("routes");
            Log.d("xxx", "array: " + array.toString());

            //Routes is a combination of objects and arrays
            JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
            Log.d("xxx", "routes: " + routes.toString());

            //String summary = routes.getString("summary");
            //Log.d("JSON","summary: "+summary);

            JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
            Log.d("xxx", "legs: " + legs.toString());

            JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
            Log.d("JSON", "steps: " + steps.toString());

            JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
            Log.d("xxx", "distance: " + distance.toString());

            String sDistance = distance.getString("text");
            int iDistance = distance.getInt("value");

            Log.d("SEE THE DIST : ", "" + sDistance + iDistance);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As this function performs networking operation we must use AsyncTask as follows:

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            GetDistance(from, to);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

LOG CAT:

```
01-05 17:01:08.657 3736-3820/in.test D/xxx: URL=http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=MP+Chowk+Thane+West+Thane,+Maharashtra+400080+&destination=Ghatkopar+West,+Mumbai,+Maharashtra,+India&mode=driving&sensor=true
01-05 17:01:08.687 3736-3736/in.test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-05 17:01:08.687 3736-3736/in.test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-05 17:01:08.797 3736-3778/in.test V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
01-05 17:01:08.807 3736-3778/in.test V/RenderScript: 0xb97768c0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
01-05 17:01:09.097 3736-3820/in.test D/xxx: array: [{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.1885561,"lng":72.9686183},"southwest":{"lat":19.0842303,"lng":72.9075409}},"copyrights":"Map data ©2016 Google","legs":[{"distance":{"text":"15.8 km","value":15818},"duration":{"text":"26 mins","value":1562},"end_address":"Ghatkopar West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","end_location":{"lat":19.0908134,"lng":72.9076817},"start_address":"MP Chowk, Thane West, Thane, Maharashtra 400080, India","start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"steps":[{"distance":{"text":"27 m","value":27},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":6},"end_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"html_instructions":"Head <b>northeast<\/b> on <b>MP Chowk<\/b> toward <b>SG Barve Rd<\/b>","polyline":{"points":"{dbtBsch|L?AA?AA?AA??AAAAA?A?A?AAA?A?A?A?A?A?A@A?A@A?A@A?A@A"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":870},"duration":{"text":"3 mins","value":165},"end_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"html_instructions":"Exit the roundabout onto <b>Lal Bahadur Shastri Marg<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by Wagle Estate Post Office (on the left)<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"_ebtBaeh|LWoAOcAEe@A_AA{AMcBEQC]COOqAk@sDcAaE_@_Ac@}@[o@o@aAk@w@k@w@e@{@s@{AWm@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2448},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":316},"end_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"html_instructions":"Turn <b>right<\/b> to merge onto <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"gvbtBiti|LQYIOCEGKXEZGp@QvM}CnAWLCNCL?X?jFsAp@QlGaBt@Qh@Of@Mz@WXIRI`@MNGRKrB_AxCqAbCaAz@]^Mb@Mr@Ob@IbDg@v@O|B]XEvAW~@OLAPCN?Z?r@@tG^r@Df@F`@HzDt@lAZl@RrAr@bAn@vC`BtD~B"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"5.6 km","value":5599},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":320},"end_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"mx~sBuej|LnEnCnElCXNXNtFhDtFhDnc@jW|AbAtL|GZPTN@@@?B@DD@?DB`@X@?rN|I|BtAb@T~X~NzNtHd_@vRhHtDNJh@ZrCzAh@XxAt@lAn@zo@l\\p@ZdCjA~Bz@fGjB"},"start_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"1.5 km","value":1518},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":95},"end_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>left<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-left","polyline":{"points":"_jvsB{{d|LtCt@v@VxAj@jKjDj@Pt`@zLrKfD~HhC"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2371},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":139},"end_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"uzssBuzc|LrQlFd@Nd@N|XrInBn@zBp@vQpF`F|AjVpH~PfFzAh@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":921},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":54},"end_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"html_instructions":"Continue straight to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"straight","polyline":{"points":"i~osB}gb|LZJ|NlEXHTHn@R|@VvAb@tC~@b@NTHh@TB?TJNHZNTL`@T`@Vr@f@d@^`E~C"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.1 km","value":132},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":18},"end_location":{"lat":19.0842303,"lng":72.92085449999999},"html_instructions":"Take the exit on the <b>right<\/b> toward <b>Link Rd<\/b>","maneuver":"ramp-right","polyline":{"points":"cpnsBepa|LBV@@@@rBlBDDBDDF@FFT"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.3 km","value":275},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":47},"end_location":{"lat":19.0862782,"lng":72.9194201},"html_i
01-05 17:01:09.107 3736-3820/in.test D/xxx: routes: {"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.1885561,"lng":72.9686183},"southwest":{"lat":19.0842303,"lng":72.9075409}},"copyrights":"Map data ©2016 Google","legs":[{"distance":{"text":"15.8 km","value":15818},"duration":{"text":"26 mins","value":1562},"end_address":"Ghatkopar West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","end_location":{"lat":19.0908134,"lng":72.9076817},"start_address":"MP Chowk, Thane West, Thane, Maharashtra 400080, India","start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"steps":[{"distance":{"text":"27 m","value":27},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":6},"end_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"html_instructions":"Head <b>northeast<\/b> on <b>MP Chowk<\/b> toward <b>SG Barve Rd<\/b>","polyline":{"points":"{dbtBsch|L?AA?AA?AA??AAAAA?A?A?AAA?A?A?A?A?A?A@A?A@A?A@A?A@A"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":870},"duration":{"text":"3 mins","value":165},"end_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"html_instructions":"Exit the roundabout onto <b>Lal Bahadur Shastri Marg<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by Wagle Estate Post Office (on the left)<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"_ebtBaeh|LWoAOcAEe@A_AA{AMcBEQC]COOqAk@sDcAaE_@_Ac@}@[o@o@aAk@w@k@w@e@{@s@{AWm@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2448},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":316},"end_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"html_instructions":"Turn <b>right<\/b> to merge onto <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"gvbtBiti|LQYIOCEGKXEZGp@QvM}CnAWLCNCL?X?jFsAp@QlGaBt@Qh@Of@Mz@WXIRI`@MNGRKrB_AxCqAbCaAz@]^Mb@Mr@Ob@IbDg@v@O|B]XEvAW~@OLAPCN?Z?r@@tG^r@Df@F`@HzDt@lAZl@RrAr@bAn@vC`BtD~B"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"5.6 km","value":5599},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":320},"end_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"mx~sBuej|LnEnCnElCXNXNtFhDtFhDnc@jW|AbAtL|GZPTN@@@?B@DD@?DB`@X@?rN|I|BtAb@T~X~NzNtHd_@vRhHtDNJh@ZrCzAh@XxAt@lAn@zo@l\\p@ZdCjA~Bz@fGjB"},"start_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"1.5 km","value":1518},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":95},"end_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>left<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-left","polyline":{"points":"_jvsB{{d|LtCt@v@VxAj@jKjDj@Pt`@zLrKfD~HhC"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2371},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":139},"end_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"uzssBuzc|LrQlFd@Nd@N|XrInBn@zBp@vQpF`F|AjVpH~PfFzAh@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":921},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":54},"end_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"html_instructions":"Continue straight to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"straight","polyline":{"points":"i~osB}gb|LZJ|NlEXHTHn@R|@VvAb@tC~@b@NTHh@TB?TJNHZNTL`@T`@Vr@f@d@^`E~C"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.1 km","value":132},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":18},"end_location":{"lat":19.0842303,"lng":72.92085449999999},"html_instructions":"Take the exit on the <b>right<\/b> toward <b>Link Rd<\/b>","maneuver":"ramp-right","polyline":{"points":"cpnsBepa|LBV@@@@rBlBDDBDDF@FFT"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.3 km","value":275},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":47},"end_location":{"lat":19.0862782,"lng":72.9194201},"html_i
01-05 17:01:09.107 3736-3820/in.test D/xxx: legs: [{"distance":{"text":"15.8 km","value":15818},"duration":{"text":"26 mins","value":1562},"end_address":"Ghatkopar West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","end_location":{"lat":19.0908134,"lng":72.9076817},"start_address":"MP Chowk, Thane West, Thane, Maharashtra 400080, India","start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"steps":[{"distance":{"text":"27 m","value":27},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":6},"end_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"html_instructions":"Head <b>northeast<\/b> on <b>MP Chowk<\/b> toward <b>SG Barve Rd<\/b>","polyline":{"points":"{dbtBsch|L?AA?AA?AA??AAAAA?A?A?AAA?A?A?A?A?A?A@A?A@A?A@A?A@A"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":870},"duration":{"text":"3 mins","value":165},"end_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"html_instructions":"Exit the roundabout onto <b>Lal Bahadur Shastri Marg<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by Wagle Estate Post Office (on the left)<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"_ebtBaeh|LWoAOcAEe@A_AA{AMcBEQC]COOqAk@sDcAaE_@_Ac@}@[o@o@aAk@w@k@w@e@{@s@{AWm@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2448},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":316},"end_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"html_instructions":"Turn <b>right<\/b> to merge onto <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"gvbtBiti|LQYIOCEGKXEZGp@QvM}CnAWLCNCL?X?jFsAp@QlGaBt@Qh@Of@Mz@WXIRI`@MNGRKrB_AxCqAbCaAz@]^Mb@Mr@Ob@IbDg@v@O|B]XEvAW~@OLAPCN?Z?r@@tG^r@Df@F`@HzDt@lAZl@RrAr@bAn@vC`BtD~B"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"5.6 km","value":5599},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":320},"end_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"mx~sBuej|LnEnCnElCXNXNtFhDtFhDnc@jW|AbAtL|GZPTN@@@?B@DD@?DB`@X@?rN|I|BtAb@T~X~NzNtHd_@vRhHtDNJh@ZrCzAh@XxAt@lAn@zo@l\\p@ZdCjA~Bz@fGjB"},"start_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"1.5 km","value":1518},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":95},"end_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>left<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-left","polyline":{"points":"_jvsB{{d|LtCt@v@VxAj@jKjDj@Pt`@zLrKfD~HhC"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2371},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":139},"end_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"uzssBuzc|LrQlFd@Nd@N|XrInBn@zBp@vQpF`F|AjVpH~PfFzAh@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":921},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":54},"end_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"html_instructions":"Continue straight to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"straight","polyline":{"points":"i~osB}gb|LZJ|NlEXHTHn@R|@VvAb@tC~@b@NTHh@TB?TJNHZNTL`@T`@Vr@f@d@^`E~C"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.1 km","value":132},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":18},"end_location":{"lat":19.0842303,"lng":72.92085449999999},"html_instructions":"Take the exit on the <b>right<\/b> toward <b>Link Rd<\/b>","maneuver":"ramp-right","polyline":{"points":"cpnsBepa|LBV@@@@rBlBDDBDDF@FFT"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.3 km","value":275},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":47},"end_location":{"lat":19.0862782,"lng":72.9194201},"html_instructions":"Continue onto <b>Link Rd<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by A 3 (on the left)<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"mknsBija|LIRoDtB{BpAcB`A"
01-05 17:01:09.117 3736-3820/in.test D/JSON: steps: {"distance":{"text":"15.8 km","value":15818},"duration":{"text":"26 mins","value":1562},"end_address":"Ghatkopar West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","end_location":{"lat":19.0908134,"lng":72.9076817},"start_address":"MP Chowk, Thane West, Thane, Maharashtra 400080, India","start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"steps":[{"distance":{"text":"27 m","value":27},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":6},"end_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"html_instructions":"Head <b>northeast<\/b> on <b>MP Chowk<\/b> toward <b>SG Barve Rd<\/b>","polyline":{"points":"{dbtBsch|L?AA?AA?AA??AAAAA?A?A?AAA?A?A?A?A?A?A@A?A@A?A@A?A@A"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1855772,"lng":72.9556247},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":870},"duration":{"text":"3 mins","value":165},"end_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"html_instructions":"Exit the roundabout onto <b>Lal Bahadur Shastri Marg<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by Wagle Estate Post Office (on the left)<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"_ebtBaeh|LWoAOcAEe@A_AA{AMcBEQC]COOqAk@sDcAaE_@_Ac@}@[o@o@aAk@w@k@w@e@{@s@{AWm@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.185599,"lng":72.9558468},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2448},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":316},"end_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"html_instructions":"Turn <b>right<\/b> to merge onto <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"gvbtBiti|LQYIOCEGKXEZGp@QvM}CnAWLCNCL?X?jFsAp@QlGaBt@Qh@Of@Mz@WXIRI`@MNGRKrB_AxCqAbCaAz@]^Mb@Mr@Ob@IbDg@v@O|B]XEvAW~@OLAPCN?Z?r@@tG^r@Df@F`@HzDt@lAZl@RrAr@bAn@vC`BtD~B"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1883648,"lng":72.963413},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"5.6 km","value":5599},"duration":{"text":"5 mins","value":320},"end_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Partial toll road<\/div>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"mx~sBuej|LnEnCnElCXNXNtFhDtFhDnc@jW|AbAtL|GZPTN@@@?B@DD@?DB`@X@?rN|I|BtAb@T~X~NzNtHd_@vRhHtDNJh@ZrCzAh@XxAt@lAn@zo@l\\p@ZdCjA~Bz@fGjB"},"start_location":{"lat":19.16823,"lng":72.96618509999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"1.5 km","value":1518},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":95},"end_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>left<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-left","polyline":{"points":"_jvsB{{d|LtCt@v@VxAj@jKjDj@Pt`@zLrKfD~HhC"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1249579,"lng":72.9390226},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"2.4 km","value":2371},"duration":{"text":"2 mins","value":139},"end_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"html_instructions":"Keep <b>right<\/b> to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"keep-right","polyline":{"points":"uzssBuzc|LrQlFd@Nd@N|XrInBn@zBp@vQpF`F|AjVpH~PfFzAh@"},"start_location":{"lat":19.1122651,"lng":72.93371189999999},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.9 km","value":921},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":54},"end_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"html_instructions":"Continue straight to stay on <b>NH 3<\/b>","maneuver":"straight","polyline":{"points":"i~osB}gb|LZJ|NlEXHTHn@R|@VvAb@tC~@b@NTHh@TB?TJNHZNTL`@T`@Vr@f@d@^`E~C"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0923682,"lng":72.9255933},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.1 km","value":132},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":18},"end_location":{"lat":19.0842303,"lng":72.92085449999999},"html_instructions":"Take the exit on the <b>right<\/b> toward <b>Link Rd<\/b>","maneuver":"ramp-right","polyline":{"points":"cpnsBepa|LBV@@@@rBlBDDBDDF@FFT"},"start_location":{"lat":19.0849757,"lng":72.9217895},"travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"distance":{"text":"0.3 km","value":275},"duration":{"text":"1 min","value":47},"end_location":{"lat":19.0862782,"lng":72.9194201},"html_instructions":"Continue onto <b>Link Rd<\/b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by A 3 (on the left)<\/div>","polyline":{"points":"mknsBija|LIRoDtB{BpAcB`A
01-05 17:01:09.117 3736-3820/in.test D/xxx: distance: {"text":"15.8 km","value":15818}
01-05 17:01:09.117 3736-3820/in.test D/SEE THE DIST :: 15.8 km15818
```

**THANKS KENNY!**