# Walking distance android maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How to calculate the walking distance between two points in Android?

For example:

```
static final LatLng Point_One = new LatLng(41.995908, 21.431491);
static final LatLng Point_Two = new LatLng(41.996097, 21.422419);
```

Now, the distance between these points on **maps.google.com** is **950 meters**. And the `Location.distanceBetween` is returning the air line distance between these two points, I need the Walking distane. Thanks in advance.

*PS: I am using google maps Api v2*

Comment: "walking distance" is no straight line I guess?

Comment: No, it's not a straight line, imagine if between these points is a wall or a river or something.. @SteveBenett

Comment: then that's called navigation. you need to call a navigation service.

Answer (score 1):

Just request the maps API as documented in [The Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

So, your request to Maps API is :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=41.995908,%2021.431491&destinations=41.996097,%2021.422419&mode=walking&sensor=false

You just have to query this url from your application.

Comment: I saw this solution but I think is a workaround.. Is there any library that Google provides for this?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no library from Google providing it. You may check the first answer here to copy paste the code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456090/android-google-map-finding-distance/6456161#6456161

Comment: @Naskov it is not a workaround its the only solution, there is nothing besides this that gives you navigation walking distance between points

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a walking distance between two points (other than as a straight line). You could plot a track of the walk (GPX) and then calculate distance. You can do this with an App as you walk or on a map.