# How to get all possible latitude and longitude in certain radius from current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get all the possible coordinate list of locations available in certain radius for e.g. say 3km radius. How do I implement that?

I want to place pins on my map randomly within the radius of 3km from my current location

**SOLVED**
Get the current location using location services and function provided on  [this link](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java) can be used to calculate the distance between two places.

So the solution I was looking for, I've found

Comment: `list of locations available`? What does this mean?

Comment: Generate random number <0,3> what specify distance from center point and number <0,360) to specify angle. Then simply calculate actual position from current position (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance)

Comment: @MrNeo I want to get latitude and longitude which are possible in 3km radius. I'm not looking for any specific genre of place.

Comment: You could follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456090/android-google-map-finding-distance/6456161#6456161) to get `distance` and decide whether it's over 3km or not

Comment: you can face difficulty in determining all the latlng present within a certain radius . but if yu have a latlng it is very easy to check if that latlng is present within your given radius.